# Routing Error in Ruby on Rails for simple view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller, view

I am following a tutorial for building a very simple rails app. I have created a simple controller that looks like this

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
end
```

and I have a folder inside of views called animals with a rhtml file called hello.rhtml containing some basic text. Now when I start the server and go visit

`http://localhost:3000/animals/hello`

I get a Routing Error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike some frameworks, the routes are not automatically created from the methods that exist in the controller, you need the following in **config/routes.rb**

```
get "animals/hello" => "animals#hello"
```

You can read about routing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

You can find out the routes for your current project by typing `rake routes` in your terminal.

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController 
  def hello
  end
end
```

Comment: I get "The action 'hello' could not be found for AnimalsController" not quite sure still

Comment: Try adding a hello method to your controller with `def hello; end`

Comment: I sorry but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: @AndersKitson Perhaps the instruction was not clear.  I have edited it into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also you need a action method in your controller called 'hello'.

So your controller becomes:

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
    def hello
    end
end
```

Then combine Gazler's answer, the Routing Error should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

And if you wanna get all methods from `AnimalsController` visible then wrtite:

```
match 'animals/:method', :controller => 'animals'
```